# Nonlinear regression

Tags: python, python-3.x, statsmodels

I've managed to do a linear regression using statsmodels, however I would like to change the formula from

```
Y = A + X1*C1 + X2*C2 + X3*C3 + X4*C4 + DUMMY*C5
```

to

```
Y = A * (X1^C1) * e^(X2*C2+X3*C3+X4*C4)
```

I've tried to change the sm.OLS formula from a linear to a exponential, but I don't know how to write it

```
x1= df['com_proc'].values.tolist()

x2 = df['desp_pessoal'].values.tolist()
x3 = df['ln(trein)'].values.tolist()
x4 = df['out_desp'].values.tolist()
dummy = df['dummy1'].values.tolist()
y = df['ln(ro)'].values.tolist()

dados = pd.DataFrame(data=df)
dados   #Visualiza o DataFrame
print("Estatísticas descritivas de y:")
dados['y'].describe()

reg = sm.ols(formula='y~x1+x2+x3+x4+dummy', data=dados).fit()
print(reg.summary())
```

I don't know how I can fit "dummy" in the formula

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Your code does not run because (1) you do not define all variables and (2) you do not include the part where you import modules. I take it, `pd` is `pandas` and `sm` is `statsmodels.formula.api`.